# Understanding CentOS Memory usage

Tags: memory-management, centos

I am not an OS expert, and I am having trouble understanding my server's memory usage. I need your advices to understand the following:

My server has 8 GB RAM and operates as web server. PHP, mySQL and Apache processes consume the majority of the memory. When I issue the command "free" after the system is rebooted, I would normally see something along these lines:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       8059080    2277924    5781156          0        948     310852
-/+ buffers/cache:    1966124    6092956
Swap:      4194296          0    4092668
```

Obviously, sooner or later the free memory would drop and the cached memory would increase and I assume there is nothing wrong with that since the OS decides to cache it.

What I don't understand is about 1-2 days later after the machine is rebooted, I would slightly see an increase in the used swap memory. Does not this mean that the server does not have free memory anymore and using IO instead? How can I understand which processes cause this?

I am asking this question to stackoverflow users because if I ask it to my hosting provider, I am sure they would ask more money to increase RAM.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is perfectly normal. When the machine starts up, a large number of services also start up. As they run their startup code, read their configuration, and so on, they dirty some pages of memory. Many of these services will never run again. By writing this data to swap, the operating system accomplishes two things:

First, if it ever does encounter memory pressure, it can discard the pages without having to write them first, since it has already written them. Second, it can discard the pages to make more free memory to enlarge the cache.

The alternative is to keep information that hasn't been touched in days in physical memory. And that just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks David for your explanation. Based on what you are saying, how would I ever understand if the physical memory is not enough to handle this server anymore? I mean where would I look at?

Comment: You would look for a very small cache and very high disk I/O. It is not easy to diagnose memory problems on modern operating systems because their memory management is sophisticated.